# Calculating projected coordinates for rotations on a Cartesian plane

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, rotations

There are four points Blue (4,1), Purple (6,3), Red (9,3) and Green (4,5) plotted on a 1 cm Cartesian grid. I want to rotate the diagram about the Blue point anticlockwise (2nd layout) and clockwise (3rd layout) by 45 degrees and compute the coordinates for the rest of the points.

[image]

I've tried to compute the coordinates using the following equations ([in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)) and it doesn't give me the correct coordinates. I'm not sure what is the problem here. Also I would like to know how to specify the angle for a clockwise transformation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X and Y are not swapped. +ve Y axis should be in the anticlockwise direction of +ve X axis, which is here. You have just rotated the graph; axes are not swapped. Here we need to consider first a translation (to (4,1) ) then rotation (45 degrees). So after translation new coordinates will be

Blue(4,1) to Blue(0,0)

Purple (6,3), to Purple (2,2) etc.

Now applying rotation new location of Purple point will be

$x^{'} =2*\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} - 2*\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}=0\\$

$y^{'} =2*\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} + 2*\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}=2{\sqrt2}$

Now wrt. to original origin this point will be

$x = 0 +4=4$ and

$y = 1+2{\sqrt2}$

So new location for purple point will be $(4, 1+2{\sqrt2})$ not $(4,4)$

Comment: Thank you very much @amitava.

Comment: Always glad to help.